# Double clicking a hyperlink - effect on HTTP

Tags: http, hyperlink

When a user double clicks a hyperlink, exactly what happens?

Is one HTTP connection opened and then immediately closed or do two requests fire off and open two HTTP connections.

How bad is it for a user to double click a hyperlink, in terms of speed of loading the new page etc...

Answer (score 0):

any smart browser should realize while processing the second click that its already in process of loading the link target and do nothing.

Comment: Elaborate on smart browser? Any inparticular?

Comment: I would have thoguht Dan D. would be right. However I ran wireshark to check my traffic, went to a page and double clicked on a regular link. Sure enough the browser created two requests. I did this both in the latest Firefox and the latest Chrome.

Comment: Just to add the the above comment. I checked my web server logs and sure enough there were two entries for the linked page.